# Performance issue with WHERE and ORDER BY in HSQLDB

Tags: sql, jdbc, hsqldb

I have a simple table called `history_point` which contains the following columns:

- `id` - INTEGER PK
- `device_id` - INTEGER
- `registered` - TIMESTAMP
- `double_value` - DOUBLE
- `channel` - INTEGER
- `type` - VARCHAR(100)
- `int_value` - INTEGER

The table also have index defined for the following column combinations:

- `id`
- `device_id`
- `registered`
- `channel`
- `device_id`, `channel`, `registered`

The table contains approximately 200000 rows. I run queries using the Java code below.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class JdbcMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:db/homeki.db;ifexists=true");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("<SQL query goes here>");
        if (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("Registered: " + rs.getDate("registered"));
        }
        long dur = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        System.out.println("Took " + dur + " ms.");
        stmt.execute("SHUTDOWN");
        con.close();
    }
}
```

When I run the query `SELECT * FROM history_point WHERE device_id = 3 AND channel = 0 LIMIT 1`, it takes ~5 ms. If I run the query `SELECT * FROM history_point ORDER BY registered DESC LIMIT 1`, it also takes ~5 ms. **But**, if I run the query `SELECT * FROM history_point WHERE device_id = 3 AND channel = 0 ORDER BY registered DESC LIMIT 1`, it takes ~1000ms!

I guess that could have been understandable, considering what they say at http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/guide/ch02.html#N1033B, "HSQLDB does not use indexes to improve sorting of query results" (which by the way sounds strange to me).

**However**, if I run the last query in Eclipse using the Eclipse Data Tools Platform's SQL Scrapbook, it executes in ~5 ms. Any query I throw at it using the SQL Scrapbook executes in ~5 ms. Why is that? They're both using the same JDBC driver and the same database.

There are ~25000 rows in `history_point` with `device_id = 3` and `channel = 0`, if that matters.

The connection string I use is `jdbc:hsqldb:file:db/mystorage.db`. The table was created as a `CACHED` table (all data is stored on disk).

Can anyone explain this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of HSQLDB? If you are using the latest version please refer to the online version 2.x Guide.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I use HSQLDB 2.2.8, and was looking at the Guide for 1.8. Here's the same section for HSQLDB 2.X: http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlgeneral-chapt.html#sgc_index_speed. Does not seem to have the same limitation (uses index for ORDER BY). The problem still remains though..

Answer (score 1):

If the ORDER BY columns are all covered by an index, and the query condition can use a different index, then the index for the query condition is used. Currently, HSQLDB can use the index on `(device_id, channel, registered)` for the query condition, but not for sorting on the `registered` column at the same time.

In version 2.2.8, you can force the use of the index on the ORDER BY columns when there is a LIMIT clause. In this case, the index on registered is used:

```
SELECT * FROM history_point WHERE device_id = 3 AND channel = 0 
ORDER BY registered DESC LIMIT 1 USING INDEX
```

But perhaps this is the best way to use the index on the three columns:

```
SELECT * FROM history_point WHERE device_id = 3 AND channel = 0 
ORDER BY device_id DESC, channel DESC, registered DESC LIMIT 1 USING INDEX
```

Comment: That query also executes in ~1000 ms. So what you are saying is that it is reasonable for a query like this to take around 1 sec to execute? How come Eclipse SQL Scrapbook still shows ~5 ms for all mentioned queries?

Comment: Execute EXPLAIN PLAN for your queries to see which index is used. I've no idea about execution times in Eclipse.